# How to get XML data into mongodb using Rails 3?

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I've got XML data which I want to be saved in a mongodb. I'm using RESTClient to perfom a POST on the resource. The HTML status code returns that it was created. However all fields are "nil". What am I missing? Do I have to convert it to json/bson first? Is it generally possible? I'm using MongoMapper.
I also thought of using a native XML database but I couldn't seem to find any supported by Rails 3. Are there any?

Just the usual stuff in my controller:

```
def create
  @assessment = Assessment.new(params[:assessment])
  respond_to do |format|

  if @assessment.save
    format.html {redirect_to(:action => 'list')}   # backdoor for maintanance
    format.xml {render :xml => @assessment, :status => created}
  else
    *omitted*
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If `params[:assessment]` is a hash of hashes and arrays, it should work.  But if it's straight XML you'll have to have something else parse it first. e.g. [Crack](https://github.com/jnunemaker/crack) `Crack::XML.parse('<mydoc>your xml here</mydoc>')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is straight XML sent to that resource. I'll try to dig into that. I read a bit about Nokogiri but wasn't sure if that would fit. I guess that would do the job as well.

Comment: Well, sometimes strange things happen. After I fired up the webserver again for testing my code, it worked right away without changes. So no need for Crack or whatsoever.